# how to change background and fadeout table row at once

Tags: jquery

When I delete a record I want the row to change red and then fade out. I can't make it either go red or fade out, not both. I can't seem to post without typing more text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('click', ".delete-btn", function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'functions/delete-article.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response = "success") {
          tr.css('background', 'tomato', function() {});
        }
      },
    });
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'functions/list-articles-delete.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(item) {
        var tr_str = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + data[item].n_title + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + data[item].n_dateTime + "</td>" +
          "<td><button class='btn btn-danger delete-btn' data-id='" + data[item].id + "'>Delete</button></td>";
        $("#output").append(tr_str);
      });
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML example (with snippet)?

Comment: I have edited my initial code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) here to delay the `fadeOut()` after click like

```js
$('tr').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).find('td').css('background', 'tomato').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here, after you click on the `tr` element (you can change the selector here), we change the `background` of the element, and before we `fadeOut` we delay it by a second.

Comment: Thanks mr. Alien. I can't use that code because I need it to fire when I click on the delete button.  $("body").on('click', ".delete-btn", function() {

Comment: @Jonathan So you change the selector?

Comment: I did. I tried to use your code but when I clicked on the delete buttons nothing happens. No error in console either.

Comment: It seems that all I had to do was this: tr.css("background", "red");
tr.fadeOut("slow");

Comment: Instead of trying to do something after the colour change using a callback:  tr.css('background', 'tomato', function() {